# How can I Find which row to split a column into two new ones?

Tags: python, regex, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I am working through a DataFrame trying to clean things up, and came across a bit of an unusual element. Two test values are represented in the same results column posted below. I would like to split the CRP group into another 2 columns, tentatively titled "CRP_mgml" and "CRP_Result", but I am unsure how to find where my IL6 rows end and the CRP rows begin. I have a feeling I could use a regex function to parse through, but I'm pretty new to this so need some help. Thank you in advance.

```
df2[['Group_Id', 'Result']]
Out[46]: 
                                               Group_Id  Result
0     LAB\(LLB63) DBNull\(LLB64) DBNull\INTERL6\BCIL...   400.0
1     LAB\(LLB63) DBNull\(LLB64) DBNull\INTERL6\BCIL...   400.0
2     LAB\(LLB63) DBNull\(LLB64) DBNull\INTERL6\BCIL...   400.0
3     LAB\(LLB63) DBNull\(LLB64) DBNull\INTERL6\BCIL...   392.0
4     LAB\(LLB63) DBNull\(LLB64) DBNull\INTERL6\BCIL...   400.0
5     LAB\(LLB63) DBNull\(LLB64) DBNull\INTERL6\BCIL...   400.0
6     LAB\(LLB63) DBNull\(LLB64) DBNull\INTERL6\BCIL...   400.0
7     LAB\(LLB63) DBNull\(LLB64) DBNull\INTERL6\BCIL...   400.0
**8     LAB\(LLB63) DBNull\(LLB64) DBNull\INTERL6\BCIL...   400.0
9     LAB\(LLB63) DBNull\(LLB64) DBNull\INTERL6\BCIL...   328.0
10    LAB\(LLB63) DBNull\(LLB64) DBNull\INTERL6\BCIL...   400.0
11    LAB\(LLB63) DBNull\(LLB64) DBNull\INTERL6\BCIL...   400.0
12    LAB\(LLB63) DBNull\(LLB64) DBNull\INTERL6\BCIL...   400.0
13    LAB\(LLB63) DBNull\(LLB64) DBNull\INTERL6\BCIL...   400.0
14    LAB\(LLB63) DBNull\(LLB64) DBNull\INTERL6\BCIL...   400.0
15    LAB\(LLB63) DBNull\(LLB64) DBNull\INTERL6\BCIL...   400.0
16    LAB\(LLB63) DBNull\(LLB64) DBNull\INTERL6\BCIL...    70.9
17    LAB\(LLB63) DBNull\(LLB64) DBNull\INTERL6\BCIL...     3.4
18    LAB\(LLB63) DBNull\(LLB64) DBNull\INTERL6\BCIL...     2.6
19    LAB\(LLB63) DBNull\(LLB64) DBNull\INTERL6\BCIL...     1.9
20    LAB\(LLB63) DBNull\(LLB64) DBNull\INTERL6\BCIL...    30.0
21    LAB\(LLB63) DBNull\(LLB64) DBNull\INTERL6\BCIL...    19.3
22    LAB\(LLB63) DBNull\(LLB64) DBNull\INTERL6\BCIL...    39.4
23    LAB\(LLB63) DBNull\(LLB64) DBNull\INTERL6\BCIL...    17.0
24    LAB\(LLB63) DBNull\(LLB64) DBNull\INTERL6\BCIL...    36.9
25    LAB\(LLB63) DBNull\(LLB64) DBNull\INTERL6\BCIL...     2.6
26    LAB\(LLB63) DBNull\(LLB64) DBNull\INTERL6\BCIL...    10.4
27    LAB\(LLB63) DBNull\(LLB64) DBNull\INTERL6\BCIL...     3.4
28    LAB\(LLB63) DBNull\(LLB64) DBNull\INTERL6\BCIL...    11.3
29    LAB\(LLB63) DBNull\(LLB64) DBNull\INTERL6\BCIL...   281.0
                                                ...     ...
4558                                         CRP (mg/L)     1.5
4559                                         CRP (mg/L)     2.0
4560                                         CRP (mg/L)     5.3
4561                                         CRP (mg/L)     0.8
4562                                         CRP (mg/L)     1.2
4563                                         CRP (mg/L)     2.0
4564                                         CRP (mg/L)     2.6
4565                                         CRP (mg/L)     3.1
4566                                         CRP (mg/L)     3.9
4567                                         CRP (mg/L)     5.5
4568                                         CRP (mg/L)     7.8
4569                                         CRP (mg/L)    13.0
4570                                         CRP (mg/L)    20.2
4571                                         CRP (mg/L)    25.0
4572                                         CRP (mg/L)    24.8
4573                                         CRP (mg/L)    42.3
4574                                         CRP (mg/L)    71.0
4575                                         CRP (mg/L)   171.2
4576                                         CRP (mg/L)   271.6
4577                                         CRP (mg/L)   289.0
4578                                         CRP (mg/L)   148.7
4579                                         CRP (mg/L)    77.3
4580                                         CRP (mg/L)    69.0
4581                                         CRP (mg/L)    68.5
4582                                         CRP (mg/L)    69.7
4583                                         CRP (mg/L)   125.5
4584                                         CRP (mg/L)    41.9
4585                                         CRP (mg/L)    12.9
4586                                         CRP (mg/L)     4.1
4587                                         CRP (mg/L)    10.9
[4588 rows x 2 columns]**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your group ID for all of the CRP rows is the same. If this is true, you could create 2 new data frames based on group_id.

It would look something like:

```
crpDF = df2[df2.Group_Id == "CRP (mg/L)"]
il6DF = df2[~(df2.Group_Id == "CRP (mg/L)")]
```

the wavy line (~) is a negation symbol so it will take the series returned by (df.Group_Id == 'CRP (mg/L)') and return the opposite.

I like this solution because it doesn't depend on the df being sorted.

Comment: it worked well for the crp group, but using the negation symbol returned an error "bad operand type for unary: str"

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot to put in parentheses. I've updated the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not split using `.split()`?

```
df2.Group_Id.str.split('Put the rule to split by in here')
```